# Can I map /status and /status/:id if I use nodejs and angular.js?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, routes, node.js-connect

I have some problems to route /status and /status/:id. I get "cannot get /status" error message

In angular I have written:

```
App.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/status', {
        templateUrl:    'views/statusList',
        controller:     'dailyStatusCtrl'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/status/:oldDate', {
        templateUrl:    'views/statusList',
        controller:     'dailyStatusCtrl'
    });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
}]);
```

And on the nodejs side I use jade und have written:

```
server.use(connRoute(function(router){
    router.get('/', function (req, res, next){
      console.log('/ router');
      res.render('index');
    });
    router.get('/views/:view', function(req, res){
        res.render(req.params.view)
    });
    router.get('status/:id', function (req, res, next){
        console.log('status * router');
        res.render('index');
    });
    router.get('*', function (req, res, next){
        console.log('** router');
        res.render('index');
    });
}));
```

The part for /status/:id is a test. But it's not working. I get the message: "cannot get /status" for "/status" but it works for "/status/somecontent".

What's wrong in my code? How can I use /status und /status/:id ?

Without the second router I get "cannot get /status/somecontent" but it's working for /status.

Thanks

**Edit 1:**

I have edit my routes in node to:

```
server.use(connRoute(function(router){
    router.get('/', function (req, res, next){
      res.render('index');
    });
    router.get('/views/:view', function(req, res, next){
        res.render(req.params.view)
    });
}));
```

and add connect-modrewrite:

```
server.use(modRewrite([
    '^([^.]+)$ /index.html [L]'
]));
```

But the rewrite Rule is wrong. I can't reload only the main page (/). Any other page is not reload able. Or is it a problem in the order?

This is the actually order:

```
server.use(connRoute(function(router){
    router.get('/', function (req, res, next){
      res.render('index');
    });
    router.get('/views/:view', function(req, res, next){
        res.render(req.params.view)
    });
}));


server.use(modRewrite([
    '^([^.]+)$ /index.html [L]'
]));


server.use(servStatic(__dirname + '/../logbook'));
```

Any Idea for the right modRewrite Rule?

Comment: If you're routing it in angular, you don't need to route it server-side.

Comment: If I remove the router for status/:id I get a "cannot get /status/somecontent". I think the config for angular is okay. But in node is something wrong.
I suppose it's something with htmlMode.

Comment: and you have no route server-side with `/status` or `status`

Comment: are you sure `views/statusList` exists and renders the way you expect?

Comment: no, /status working with the * route. It's loading the right template as well. only /status/123 is not working.

Comment: Which router(s) does it hit on your server when you go to /status/123? It should be hitting `*`, then `/views/:view`

Comment: If I hit the / page, then the router with '/' take the request. If I hit /status, then the router with '*' takes the request. 
But if I hit /status/123 nobody handels this request (in debuger: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)). But why?

Comment: My guess is the `*` route isn't doing what you think it does. I can't find any documentation on wildcard routes for connect. I did see this in the changelog though: "support wildcard for both type and subtype (`*/*`)" I suggest trying `*/*`

Answer (score 0):

Without modrewrite it works if you have for each url an entry for router. Don't forget to use "function (req, res, next)".

```
server.use(connRoute(function(router){
    router.get('/', function (req, res, next){
      res.render('index');
    });
    router.get('/status', function (req, res, next){
      res.render('index');
    });
    router.get('/status/:olddate', function (req, res, next){
      res.render('index');
    });
    router.get('/views/:view', function(req, res, next){
        res.render(req.params.view)
    });
}));
```